# xcode memory graph not show retain cycle

Tags: xcode, swift4.2, retain-cycle, memory-graph-debugger

My swift code is below. I have used self in closure but when I run project, memory graph does not show retain cycle. I am wrong about there is a retain cycle?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var counter = 0

    private var closure : (() -> ()) = { }

    func foo() {
        closure()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        closure = {
            self.counter += 1
            print(self.counter)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Xcode does not always visually represent the strong reference cycle. But it is consistent in showing that the object in question has not yet been deallocated.

For example, if I push via a navigation controller and pop, I see the `ViewController` in the list of live objects, but when I select it, don’t see any cycle, but rather see some cryptic graph including the navigation controller (even though I popped it off):

[image]

That having been said, I find that if I present modally and dismiss the view controller in question, I will see the cycle more clearly:

[image]

It would be nice if we could see the prototypical cycle (like shown below), but the picture isn’t always that simple when dealing with UIKit objects.

[image]